# How do GNU sort deal with the same keys?

Tags: sorting

As we know, `sort -k 2,2n` would sort a file accoding to its second column. But if the file contains with multile rows with the same values in the second column, How would GNU sort deal with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want the `-s` option:

> The `--stable (-s)` option disables this last-resort comparison so that lines in which all fields compare equal are left in their original relative order

Answer (score 0):

The `-s` argument is used for stable sorts (will preserve previous relative ordering).

If the `-s` (stable sort) parameter is not provided, there will be a last-resort comparison (full-line) to determine the ordering.